# Questions about pairing Bluetooth (Xamrin.ios or ios)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have some questions about pairing Bluetooth.

1. Is there any events that can help me to get the pair authentication status? (e.g. after typed-password, authenticate success, authenticate fail, etc…)
2. Is there any properties I can use to get the pair authentication status? (if question 1 has no solution) (e.g. paired, unpaired, paring)
3. How can I remove the Bluetooth authorize programmatically? (it means when I remove the authorize, I will re-type password to pair my device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pairing in Core Bluetooth is initiated when you attempt to read (or write) a characteristic that has  an encryption-required property.

Once pairing is complete you will be able to read (or write) the characteristic.  If pairing is cancelled or does not complete then you will not be able to read/write the characteristic.

Pairing status can be inferred from the availability of the encrypted characteristic data

There is no way to remove the pairing programatically - It must be done by the user in the Bluetooth Settings.